# What does the tag SBAR mean in Stanford’s parse-tree representation?

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, parse-tree

When the [Online Stanford Parser tool](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/) is fed this original sentence:

> After she ate the cake, Emma visited Tony in his room.

It produces the following parse-tree representation as its output:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (SBAR (IN After)
      (S
        (NP (PRP she))
        (VP (VBD ate)
          (NP (DT the) (NN cake)))))
    (, ,)
    (NP (NNP Emma))
    (VP (VBD visited)
      (NP
        (NP (NNP Tony))
        (PP (IN in)
          (NP (PRP$ his) (NN room)))))
    (. .)))
```

My questions are:

1. What does the `SBAR` tag mean?
2. Why are there two different `S` tags?
3. What is the correct NLP parse-tree representation of this sentence?

Answer (score 27):

SBAR stands for Subordinate Clause (see [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.9.8216&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). In your case the subordinate clause starts with the subordinate conjunction *After*